# WiFi or Bluetooth (or USB) for iPad Tethering

Tags: ipad, wifi, bluetooth, tethering

How do the three tethering options for the iPad compare in the following areas:

- Range
- Security
- Speed
- Power usage (both laptop and iPad)

I'm mainly looking for the difference between WiFi and Bluetooth, as USB is pretty obvious except for the speed category.

Comment: And I guess one other advantage to WiFi is that you can connect multiple devices, which is not true for USB, though I can't speak to Bluetooth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Range

1. Wifi is the best
2. Bluetooth shorter
3. USB length of cable (there are 10' USB cables for iPad)

Security

1. USB is the best *assuming* you have decent physical security
2. Wifi is pretty good if you use *WPA2*
3. Bluetooth is the lowest probably

Speed (usually all better than your 3G speeds so a moot point for 3G)

1. USB is the fastest @ 480 Mbps for USB 2.0
2. 802.11n tops out @ 150 Mbps
3. Bluetooth is by far the slowest @ ~3 Mbps

Power Usage

1. USB is the most power efficient, however the iPad will try to charge off your laptop
2. Wifi and Bluetooth are less power efficient than USB but I don't know how they compare

Bottom Line: USB is the best if range isn't an issue, If distance is needed use Wifi with WPA2

Comment: Brief,but accurate.

Comment: How secure is bluetooth? Can simply *anyone* in range connect to my hotspot?

Comment: Is the slow speed for Bluetooth still accurate as of 2018? i.e. iPhone X with Bluetooth 5.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I just did some speed benchmarks using all three methods. Using WiFi and USB gave around 8.75 Mbps, which were extremely close to the result of doing the same speed test on the phone itself beforehand, but Bluetooth was *much* slower, at around 0.5 Mbps. The difference was very noticeable when browsing.

Comment: +1 I like using Bluetooth, but will probably do much less after reading this.

Comment: My benchmarks were much closer (done using free internet speed tests though). 2.5 Mbps for wifi and half of that for bluetooth.

Comment: @Pacerier That's interesting. Do you know if your devices support Bluetooth 4.0? I can't remember whether I was testing with a Bluetooth 2.1 or 4.0 device (I really should have mentioned that in the post.)

Comment: @JonColverson, hmm how do you check the version?

Comment: @Pacerier Looking up the specs for your model on Wikipedia is the best way I know of. :)

Comment: @JonColverson, I'm using iPhone 4. I mean is there any way to check it on the phone itself?